# Outside vents for drainage - name?

Tags: drainage, venting

Right outside of my house there are vents (for sewage?) that look like this:
[image: Outside vents]

These are ugly, take up space and a trip hazard. These can be easily pulled out (I just did with my hands) and below them there are pipes going towards the house. All other houses in the neighbourhood have these as well, but some of these been replaced by a flatter version - i.e. grills that take a lot less space and can be driven over. I'd like to do the same, so I can walk there or park my car over them.

Now the question - **what are these called**? So I can search for them online or explain in a shop without going into a lengthy tirade.

Also, **could there be any problems with replacing these** with just grill-covers? As I understand, these are for pressure relieve and there should be no problems.

Location is North East of Scotland if that matters.

Comment: I’m not familiar with those, but I typed “septic tank vent” into google images  and had some luck. “Outdoor sewer vent” had similar luck but also included rooftop options, which of course you’re not interested in.

Comment: I'd say there is a reason these stick up so high, perhaps prevention of accidental burial. Why don't you ask the appropriate regulatory agency about alternatives. I wouldn't want to park my car over a sewer vent. Also repeatedly driving a car over this area would compact the soil and might harm the pipes below.

Comment: @JimStewart I'm planning to get this space converted into a parking spot by professionals in a couple months, but I need extra space for a short period of time just now.

Comment: How can you convert it to a car park when there are sewer vents there? Are you planning on petitioning for relocation of these vents?

Comment: @JimStewart plan was to replace these vents with a flat ones. Once time comes I'll have a conversation about this with the company who is going to do it. Good point raised about pipes underneath - something to consider. I've seen neighbours doing it, so there must be a good way to do this.

Comment: Shouldn't you yourself communicate with the local building code regulatory authority about the proper treatment for this? On one occasion I left it up to a tradesman to do this and got something not in compliance.